# If there was a certification exam for statisticians, what would be the syllabus?

Tags: careers

If there was a certification exam for statisticians, what would be the syllabus, including the recommended reading material (to give an idea of the level of the exam)?

Comment: Some related questions: [What theories should every statistician know?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22804/10525), [What is it that a statistician does?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5457/10525)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Royal Statistical Society offers [three levels of professional exam in statistics](http://rss.org.uk/site/cms/contentChapterView.asp?chapter=12). Their documentation includes the [syllabuses (pdf)](http://rss.org.uk/uploadedfiles/userfiles/files/Syllabus%20for%202012.pdf) and a [series of reading lists](http://rss.org.uk/site/cms/contentviewarticle.asp?article=653). Far too much material to summarise here!

Comment: All of the links return a 404 I'm unable to find the correct ones.

Comment: I can't find any reference to an "exam" on the RSS' website either https://rss.org.uk/search/?searchtext=exam. And, unless I missed something, a quick scan through https://rss.org.uk/membership/professional-development/accreditation-scheme/ suggests RSS' accreditation does not rely on exams (anymore?). This accepted answer is probably outdated by now.

Answer (score 1):

The American Statistical Association, The Royal Statistical Society, and the australian and Canadian societies all have certification.  In the case of ASA where I have certification and RSS where I have an application in, there is not a required test.  They look for information from your CV and references.